# Does $c^n = O(2^n)$ and $log_c(n) = O(log_2(n))$ for any constant $c$?

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o-notation

I thought they did, but recently I tried to express $3^n$ as $k \times 2^n + o(2^n)$ for some constant $k$ but wasn't able to. All I found was $3^n = (\frac{3}{2})^n 2^n$. What am I misunderstanding here?

I suppose my question applies to $log_c(n) = O(log_2(n))$ as well.

Comment: $c^n\neq O(2^n)$. Actually, $c^n=O(a^n)$ for any $a\geq c$.
But $log_c(n)=(log_2(n))/(log_2(c))=O(log_2(n))$.
I prefer you to look at the definition of O again.

Comment: @user5876164 Why would I need to look at the definition of O? It's perfectly clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to already answered in user5876164's comment let me say, that you cannot express $3^n=k \times 2^n+o(2^n)$, because if we assume it for some $k$, then we obtain: $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n=k+o(1)$, which is impossible, as $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n \to \infty$.

Comment: Ok, so my reasoning was correct, it was rather me presuming that $3^n = O(2^n)$ for a long time was incorrect.

Comment: Yes. Of course, correct is $2^n=O(3^n)$.